# How to get index in Vue slots

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, slot

In the parent component I render a Carousel component (child component) and pass the content of the slot inside.

Inside the carousel component, I want to get the index of the slot content and pass it to run a function `changeSlide(index)`. How can I get the index of the passed content from inside the `<slot>`?

Parent Component

```
<Carousel>
  <template #menu="{onChangeSlide}">
    <template v-for="(label, index) in args.testLabel" :key="index">
      <Button @click="onChangeSlide" :label="label" :index="index" />
    </template>
  </template>
</Carousel>
```

Carousel component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot
      name="menu"
      :on-change-slide="() => changeSlide(index)". //Want to get the index of the content here
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: `@click="onChangeSlide(index)"`. check this. hope work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I changed it to `<Button @click="onChangeSlide(index)" :label="label" :index="index" />` but unfortunately the index is still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to do it like this.

I changed `@click="onChangeSlide"` to `@click="onChangeSlide(index)"` in the parent but also had to change `:on-change-slide="() => changeSlide(index)"` to `:on-change-slide="changeSlide"` in the carousel component.

Parent component

```
<Carousel>
  <template #menu="{onChangeSlide}">
    <template v-for="(label, index) in args.testLabel" :key="index">
      <Button @click="onChangeSlide(index)" :label="label" :index="index" />
    </template>
  </template>
</Carousel>
```

Carousel component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot
      name="menu"
      :on-change-slide="changeSlide"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```